# Hadoop MapReduce: using MapWritable as a key

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

I want to pass a `Map<String, String>` from my Mapper to the Reducer.

So the tuple I want is: `<(Sorted)MapWritable,IntWritable>`

Currently, this is dodged by the poor man's serialization: I create a simple `Text` object using Guava -s MapJoiner and MapSplitter classes, which produce `String` which then can be used to initialize the `Text` object to write. So I am transferring the key-value pairs in a String, which is then Splitted back.

But I want to drop this hack.

I know that if `mapred.output.key.comparator` is not set, then the used key class must implement `WritableComparable`. The problem is, MapWritable and SortedMapWritable lacks this interface.

I checked the `WritableComparable` interface, but I'm a bit confused, because you have to re-invent the write-read methods (serialization), not just `compareTo()`.

So my question: can you help me finding a WORKING example, code, guideline or any valuable info? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can extends `MapWritable`(or `SortedMapWritable`) and implement `WritableComparable`. You do not need to rewrite write-read methods since `MapWritable`(or `SortedMapWritable`) has done it for you.
For example,

```
public class MyMapWritable extends MapWritable implements
        WritableComparable<MyMapWritable> {

    @Override
    public int compareTo(MyMapWritable o) {
        // Implement your compare logic
        return 0;
    }
}

public class MySortedWritable extends SortedMapWritable implements
        WritableComparable<MySortedWritable> {

    @Override
    public int compareTo(MySortedWritable o) {
        // Implement your compare logic
        return 0;
    }
}
```